# Boot at a 8-10 s standstill after "Running /scripts/init-premount ... done."

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my PC alongside Windows 10 (dual boot). I have near to no experience in Linux, this is my first time using a Linux distro. And every time I boot into Ubuntu, I see the logs go by until it reaches

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
```

After this it comes to a halt for a good few seconds (8-10 seconds) and then carries on with

```
Begin: Mounting root file system...
```

And it boot properly after that, and everything later is fine.

However this slows down the entire process by quite some time. In comparison, Windows 10 would have booted up faster.

Is this intended? Or is there a bug I don't know?

Some other discussions on the internet suggested checking the UUID of the swap and copying that value into the grub file. I tried replicating the steps to no avail.

I am running on a
i5-2400 3.10GHz
4gb RAM
2 TB HDD

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo systemd-analyze blame` and `sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`.

Comment: Some things to check or change: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster